# Make text fall below an image if it cannot be displayed with a certain width

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code

```
<img src="xxxxx.png" style="float:left"/>
<p>Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. </p>
```

If the screen is wide enough, the texts display on the right of the image, which is good.

If the screen is narrow, the texts display below the image, which is good.

However, when the screen is in the transition stage (a little wider than the image width), the texts are narrowed displayed on the right of the image. How can I make sure the texts can occupy a min width of, say 30em, otherwise let it go under the image?

Comment: There is one double inverted comma which has to be removed in the code for style attribute

Comment: You just said it, `p { min-width:30em;}`

Comment: Please let me know if my answer addresses ur question well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries.

```
img {
   float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: ???px) {
   img {
       float: none;
   }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkf540ff/).

**UPDATE**

If you want to manipulate the `p` element instead of removing `float` on the `img`, you can add `clear` style to `p`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: ???px) {
    p {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or3g3pwd/1/).

Comment: Is it possible to specify the style of the paragraph only? Substracting width isn't interesting if there are more images.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "max-width" part... I don't want to calculate the width of the screen every time. Instead, I want to see how the paragraph width changes.

Comment: @xudev, I'm not quite sure what you mean by *calculate the width of the screen every time*. You only have to specify it once in CSS. If you have various images in this sort of scenario, you can give them unique classes based on their width (range) and manipulate their `float` properties through media queries accordingly. You can't give an element a conditional property based on another property through CSS alone. You need javascript for that.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** Let the image `float:left` and the text `display:table-cell` then set a `min-width` (wich will be the breaking point) and a `width` for the text. But if you want a text block with a fixed size instead, just set its `min-width` and `width` with the same value. On the below snippet, click on 'full page' then resize the browser window to check the result.

```css
* {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: orange;
    font-family: arial;
}

#image {
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
    float:left
}

#textbox {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 400px; 
    min-width: 200px;  
}
```

```html
<img id=image alt=image src="http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg">
<p id=textbox>
    Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts.
    Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner solution.

the html is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container--image pull-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
    </div>
    <div class="container--content pull-left">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is your css** which makes the content span 100% if the width is under 500px.

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}

.pull-left {
   float: left;
}

.container--image, .container--content {
   display: block;
}

.container--image {
   margin-right: 20px;
}

.container--content {
   width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .container--content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jftu6fw/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to use media-queries. You may just add `overflow: hidden` to the `<p>` element, with the **desired threshold width** as `min-width`.

```css
img{
  float: left;
}
p{
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x100/984567/ffffff">
<p>Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. </p>
```